# call function on javascript array only if it exists, return empty array otherwise

Tags: javascript

what would be a good (concise) way in Javascript (ES6) to run a method (say, "sort") on an array only when the array exists, and return an empty array otherwise?

e.g. in this example "this.props.items" can be undefined and I don't want this to fail with "Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined":

```
const sortedItems = this.props.items.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Comment: `(this.props.items || []).sort(...`

Answer (score 1):

> `const sortedItems = this.props.items ?  this.props.items.sort() : []`

Basically the same as Tushar but without unnecessary sort.

Comment: Each unnecessary sort is likely to take less than one microsecond.